# Как убедиться, что пользователь будет писать именно цифры, а не буквы в заданной задаче?

Tags: c++

Как убедиться, что пользователь будет писать именно цифры, а не буквы в заданной задаче?

```
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int x, y, z, h;

    cout << "vvedite summu pokupki\n";
    cin >> x;

    cout << "vvedite prosent skidki\n";
    cin >> y;

    h = x*y / 100;
    z = x - h;

    cout << "summa k oplate=" << z << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Самое простое и адекватное - читать сначала строку символов, а потом ее парсить. Можно, конечно, заморочиться с флагами ввода, но это того не стоит.

Answer (score 1):

Ввести он в любом случае может что угодно - это терминал, программа его не контролирует. Если просто проверить, что человек ввел число:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    int test;
    cin >> test;
    if (!cin) {
        cout << "Wrong!" << endl;
    }
}
```

Слишком сильно заморачиваться этим не стоит - в реальности таким образом входные данные не получают практически никогда.